# Oracle recursively calculate total base on tax

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have a temp table like this:

```
id  d           tax_rate    money
1   20210101    5           100
1   20210201    15          0   
1   20210301    20          0   
1   20210401    5           0
```

This is the output I want to select:

```
id  d           tax_rate    money   total
1   20210101    5           100     105
1   20210201    15          105     120.75
1   20210301    20          120.75  144.9
1   20210401    5           144.9   152.145
```

This means that I need to recursively calculate the `total` based on `tax_rate` and `previous total` (in first day previous total = money).
`total = previous total (by date) * (1 + tax_rate)` (tax_rate in percentage)

I tried using `LAG() OVER()` but `LAG` only calculate previous, not recursively so from 3rd day the calculated return wrong total.

In my case, if I can use LAG or any function to multiple all the previous tax_rate (e.g 1.05 * 1.15 * 1.2 = 1.449) then I can calculate the right `previous total`, but no luck to find a function to do that.

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210101 AS d, 5 AS tax_rate, 1000 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210201 AS d, 15 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210301 AS d, 20 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210401 AS d, 5 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual 
)
SELECT * 
FROM tmp;
```

Comment: How can 2nd row `total=120.75`? what's the logic?

Comment: How does `money` go from 1000 in the source table to 100 in the output table on 1/1?

Comment: @JustinCave sorry, 100, just typo

Comment: @D-Shih `total = previous total (by date) * (1 + tax_rate) `, in this case `105 * (1 + 15/100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be something like this

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210101 AS d, 5 AS tax_rate, 100 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210201 AS d, 15 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210301 AS d, 20 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 AS id, 20210401 AS d, 5 AS tax_rate, 0 AS money FROM dual 
),
running_total( id, d, tax_rate, money, total )
as (
  select id, d, tax_rate, money, money * (1 + tax_rate/100) total
    from tmp
   where money != 0
  union all
  select t.id, t.d, t.tax_rate, t.money, rt.total * (1 + t.tax_rate/100)
    from tmp t
         join running_total rt
           on t.id = rt.id
          and to_date( rt.d, 'yyyyddmm' ) = to_date( t.d, 'yyyyddmm' ) - 1
)
select *
  from running_total;
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=157e796733115bee1ea3887b99558ef2).

I am assuming that the first row, which forms the base of the recursive CTE, is the row where `money != 0` (so there would be only one such row per `id`).  You could change that to pick the row with the earliest date per `id` or whatever other "first row" logic your actual data supports.

Note that life will be easier for you if you use actual dates for dates rather than using numbers that represent dates.  For a 4 row virtual table, it won't matter much that you have to do a `to_date` on both sides of the join in the `running_total` recursive CTE.  But for a real table with a decent number of rows, you'd want to be able to have an index on `(id, d)` to get decent performance.  You could, of course, create a function-based index but then you'd either need to explicitly specify things like the NLS environment in your `to_date` call or deal with the potential for sessions not to use your index if their NLS environment doesn't match the NLS settings used to create the index.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use mathematical formulas to do accumulate for multiplication.

Then calculate money by the accumulate for multiplication.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  ID, D, tax_rate, 
        SUM(money) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) * EXP(SUM(LN(CAST(tax_rate AS DECIMAL(5,2))/100 + 1))over(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY d)) total
FROM tmp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f06e3/15/0)**:

```
| ID |        D | TAX_RATE |   TOTAL |
|----|----------|----------|---------|
|  1 | 20210101 |        5 |     105 |
|  1 | 20210201 |       15 |  120.75 |
|  1 | 20210301 |       20 |   144.9 |
|  1 | 20210401 |        5 | 152.145 |
```